# ptr_fun with a lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following program that uses ptr_fun with a lambda function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string target="aa";
    vector<string> v1;
    v1.push_back("aa");
    v1.push_back("bb");
    auto stringcasecmp=[](string lhs, string rhs)->int
    {
        return strcasecmp(lhs.c_str(), rhs.c_str());
    };

    auto pos = find_if(
        v1.begin(), v1.end(),
        not1( bind2nd(ptr_fun(stringcasecmp), target) )
        );

    if ( pos != v1.end())
    cout <<   "The search for `" << target << "' was successful.\n"
        "The next string is: `" << pos[1] << "'.\n";
}
```

I get the following error messages.

```
stackoverflow.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
stackoverflow.cpp:21:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘ptr_fun(main()::<lambda(std::string, std::string)>&)’
stackoverflow.cpp:22:6: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
```

How do i amend the code (minimally) to make it compile?

Comment: Just a little sidenote: If you are planning on using a lambda like the one you have here a lot, you might consider passing the arguments as reference. Save lot of string copying.

Comment: You might find that your `stringcasecmp` lambda is recursive!

Comment: @quamrana Why is it recursive?

Comment: @ggg - Oh! Sorry, I saw `strcasecmp` and said to myself 'string case compare' which became `stringcasecmp`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`bind2nd` (§D.9) and `ptr_fun` (§D.8.2.1) are deprecated in C++11. You could just write another lambda function in `find_if`:

```
auto pos = find_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                   [&](const std::string& s) {
                        return !stringcasecmp(s, target); 
                   });
```

---

`ptr_fun(<lambda>)` will not work, because `ptr_fun` is designed for C++03 to convert a function pointer to a function object for other adaptors. A lambda is already a function object, so the `ptr_fun` is unnecessary.

`bind2nd` expects the function object to define the members `second_argument_type` and `result_type`, which is not true for a lambda, so writing `bind2nd(<lambda>, target)` won't work either. But in C++11 there is a generic replacement that works:

```
std::bind(stringcasecmp, std::placeholders::_1, target)
```

However, `bind` does not return a C++03-style function object, which `not1` is expecting: it requires the type of result of `bind` to define the `argument_type` member which does not exist. Therefore the final expression

```
std::not1(std::bind(stringcasecmp, std::placeholders::_1, target))
```

will *not* work. The simplest workaround is just use another lambda I've written above.

Alternatively, you could define a generic negator:

```
template <typename Predicate>
struct generic_negate
{
    explicit generic_negate(Predicate pred) : _pred(pred) {}

    template <typename... Args>
    bool operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        return !_pred(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
private:
    Predicate _pred;
};

template <class Predicate>
generic_negate<Predicate> not_(Predicate pred)
{
    return generic_negate<Predicate>(pred);
}

....

auto pos = find_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), not_(bind(stringcasecmp, _1, target)));
```

Example: http://ideone.com/6dktf

Comment: Thanks. I think it is rather odd that bind2nd is deprecated, but the c++11 bind doesn't work with not1.

Comment: "*`ptr_fun(<lambda>)` will not work, because `ptr_fun` is designed for C++03 to convert a function pointer to a function object for other adaptors.*" Why shouldn't it work though, given that captureless lambdas are implicitly convertible to function pointers?

Comment: @ildjarn: I don't think a conversion operator will participate in template argument deduction.

Comment: Ah, now I finally know why `bind2nd(<lambda>, something)` failed when recently ran into a similar situation. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try `pointer_to_binary_function<string,string,int>(stringcasecmp)` instead of `ptr_fun(stringcasecmp)`?